# How to re-init Facebook

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, lightbox

I use the FB Javascript API to create Like-buttons. The button appears in the lightbox-view of an image based on lightbox2 (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
I create once a div with an id

```
.append($('<div/>', {
          "id": 'fb-image-like', "data-send" : 'false', "data-layout" : 'button_count', "data-width" : '250', "data-show-faces" : 'true', "data-colorscheme" : 'dark', "data-font":'arial'
      }))
```

on lightbox's "build"-event. On "updateDetails" (Show next image) I set the data-href-attribute, append the "fb-like"-class and start window.fbAsyncInit();

```
$('.fb-like').removeClass("fb-like");
        //FB._initialized = false;
        $("#fb-image-like").attr("data-href", url).addClass("fb-like");
        window.fbAsyncInit();
```

Facebook creates the iframe with Like-button and everything works perfectly. On next image the generated code looks good (replaced data-href) but the Like-Button appears as already liked, because the URL in like.php doesn't change. The `window.fbAsyncInit();` doesn't re-init the session. If I dislike now, the last image will be disliked. What can I do, to re-init the Facebook-session completely?

Comment: It looks like Facebook compares the current location.href with its database and NOT the content of the data-href-attribute. But in my ImageGallery the URL is always the same. And so all images are liked or disliked.

Answer (score 4):

> The window.fbAsyncInit(); doesn't re-init the session.

Of course it does not, because that’s not it’s purpose *at all*.

Just call FB.XFBML.parse again (probably with a scope parameter), to have it re-parse your like button tag.

Comment: Now I've added a <fb:like> and update its href-attribute everytime I toggle the image. But it's always the same. It doesn't matter what URL is set. Facebook takes only the first:
 $('#fbLikeButton').attr('href', url); // set new URL
  alert("Update button with: " + $('#fbLikeButton').attr('href'));
  FB.XFBML.parse(); // URL is new but Button looks and works like before.

Comment: Try removing the old button completely from the document, before adding the new one & parsing it.